# foreach loop for fulltext search in boolean mode

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search

I have php code which fetches `names of toys` from `words` table and matches these words in `toys_text` field of `toys` table using Boolean mode fulltext search and displays `names of toys` for `users` and **counts of toys and unique users** on webpage.

The names of toys can be either one word or combination of words. We want to fetch those results from `toys` which has `toys_text` field having all the words of the word combinations from `words` table

(example - If `words` table has entry called `blue car` - BOTH `blue` and `car` should be present in the `toys` table `toys_text` field for a match). The database changes over time with new toys with their users being added and outdated toys with their users removed.

I am facing issue in properly converting the array to string to input into the Boolean fulltext search. I using `foreach` loop and want to output +(blue) +(car) but it is only inseting +(car) into the Boolean full text query.

echo $query1 outputs

```
`select COUNT(*) as 'count', COUNT(DISTINCT tw.screen_name) AS 'cnt' from 
tweets tw join users us on tw.user_id=us.user_id WHERE MATCH (tweet_text) 
AGAINST (' +(car)' IN BOOLEAN MODE)`
```

while I would like the query to output as

```
`select COUNT(*) as 'count', COUNT(DISTINCT tw.screen_name) AS 'cnt' from 
tweets tw join users us on tw.user_id=us.user_id WHERE MATCH (tweet_text) 
AGAINST ('+(blue) +(car)' IN BOOLEAN MODE)`
```

This is my code -

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM words ORDER BY `words`.`words` 
ASC";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

$i = 1;            
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){                        
    $Word = $row['words'];
    $WordsArr = explode(" ", $row['words']);
    $query = "";

       if(count($WordsArr) > 1){
          foreach ($WordsArr as $value) {
                    $value1 = " +"."(".$value."*".")";
                    }
           $query1 = "select COUNT(*) as 'count', COUNT(DISTINCT 
           t.name) AS 'cnt' from toys t WHERE MATCH (toys_text) AGAINST 
          ('$value1' IN BOOLEAN MODE)";
        }else{
        $query1 = "select COUNT(*) as 'count', COUNT(DISTINCT t.name) AS 
       'cnt' from toys t WHERE 
        MATCH (toys_text) AGAINST ('$WordsArr[0]* IN BOOLEAN MODE')";
        }               
        $Data1 = mysqli_query($con, $query1);
        $total1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($Data1);                     
            ?>                  
        <tr>
          <td><?php echo $i;?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row['words'];?></td>
          <td><a href="showtoys.php?word=<?php echo 
          urlencode($Word); ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo 
          $total1['count']; ?></a></td>
          <td><a href="showtoys.php?keyword=<?php echo urlencode($Word); 
          ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo $total1['cnt']; ?></a></td>                   
        </tr>
            <?php $i++;} ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you don't concatenate the string :

```
foreach ($WordsArr as $value) {
    $value1 = " +"."(".$value."*".")";
}
```

Should be :

```
$value1 = '';
foreach ($WordsArr as $value) {
    $value1 .= " +"."(".$value."*".")";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. It is working now. Can you please give some documentation for this type of concatenation ?